# Including property file in maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, pom.xml

I want to include a properties file localted in ~/props/ in a maven project.
I tried using maven properties plug-in but to no use.
Any other way to load a properties file using absolute path?

Comment: Using absolute path in maven project is generally a bad idea since it makes your build dependent on specific configuration of your local environment. I think its worth to describe why you really need this and provide some details on what exactly you tried so far - this may give others some hint on how to help.

Comment: The Maven Properties Plugin would've been my suggestion, would you elaborate on why that didn't work for you? Also, have you considered putting these properties in your `settings`?